# Create a math matrix in TikZ partition lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, matrices

I want to draw a math matrix in TikZ, where I can draw helping partition lines. So far I found it pretty simple to just draw a matrix with brackets.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}]
  {
    1  & 2   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
    3  & 2   & 0 & 1 & 0 & 20 \\
    -2 & -10 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I would like to partition the matrix with a vertical line between columns 5 and 6, and a horizontal line between rows 2 and 3. Furthermore it could nice to have "identification variables" outside the brackets (top).

[image: Matrix with formatting]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not to go entirely upstream, but there are also some non-TikZ options using the [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/%7Ekcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty) and [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}% http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty
\usepackage{blkarray}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray
\begin{document}

\[
  \kbordermatrix{%
      & x & y & z & w & r & & M \\
    & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \vrule & 10 \\
    & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \vrule & 20 \\ \cline{2-8}
    & -2 & -10 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \vrule & 0
  }
​\]

\[
  \begin{blockarray}{crrrrrrc}
    & x & y & z & w & r & M &\\
    \begin{block}{[crrrrr|rc]}
      & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 10 & \\
      & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 20 & \\ \BAhhline{~------~}
      & -2 & -10 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Matrices made using kbordermatrix and blkarray]

The code can be modified to accommodate your needs to improve alignment and spacing. In both examples you can add row indices as well.

Answer (score 5):

A basic approach:

Once you named you matrix (`mymatrix` in this case), you can refer to it in the `mymatrix-row-column` notation. Usual positioning such as `above=of` will also work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-1ex]
  \matrix (mymatrix) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right
delimiter={]}]
  {
    1  & 2   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
    3  & 2   & 0 & 1 & 0 & 20 \\
    -2 & -10 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
  };
\draw[red] (mymatrix-2-1.south west) -- (mymatrix-2-6.south east);
\draw[red] (mymatrix-1-5.north east) -- (mymatrix-3-5.south east);
\node [above=of mymatrix-1-1.north] {x};
\node [above=of mymatrix-1-2.north] {y};
\node [above=of mymatrix-1-3.north] {z};
\node [above=of mymatrix-1-4.north] {w};
\node [above=of mymatrix-1-5.north] {r};
\node [above=of mymatrix-1-6.north] {M};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible improve the vertical alignment of the "identification variables" and also position them "outside the [matrix] brackets (top)"?

Comment: The position can be changed easily by putting them in a `scope` and adding e.g. `node distance=.3cm` as an option to the `scope` environment. The alignment can be improved by changing the anchor of the nodes to `base`. For me it didn't work to put this in the options to the `scope` environment (not sure why), but adding `anchor=base` to all the nodes worked fine.

Comment: Nice solution! However for my problem, it looks like the kbordermatrix-package may be the way.